# click event on bitmap field gives exception :manager. replace :newField already has a manager

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, phonegap-plugins

i have 5 bitmap in horizontalField , when i click on bitmap then bitmap it shows exception
manager. replace :newField already has a manager
 i'm using this code:

```
hfm = new     HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER|Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
bitmapField1 = new BitmapField(mImgTable , BitmapField.FOCUSABLE) {
              protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time )
              { try{
                  //Dialog.alert("image changed");
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField1, bitmapField6);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField2, bitmapField);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField3, bitmapField);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField4, bitmapField);
                  hfm.replace(bitmapField5, bitmapField);

              }catch(Exception e){ 
                 Dialog.alert("choose only one"+e);
              }
                  return true;
              }
          };
      hfm.add( bitmapField1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From description of replace method:

> replace: Removes a field from this Manager and replaces it with
>   another field. The specified oldField must be a direct child of this
>   manager and the specified newField must not be being managed by any
>   Manager, including this one.

Here you are substituting bitmapField to other ones more than once to the same Manager:

```
              hfm.replace(bitmapField2, bitmapField);
              hfm.replace(bitmapField3, bitmapField);
              hfm.replace(bitmapField4, bitmapField);
              hfm.replace(bitmapField5, bitmapField);
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont replace your HorizontalFieldmanager like that hfm.replace(bitmapField1, bitmapField6);. Just replce your image like that bitmapField1.setBitmap(bitmapField6); for All your images ..

Its working in my case

Answer (score 0):

Before replacing bitmapField you must have to initialize it.